# "Cannot iterate over string" error on converting .json to csv using jq

Tags: json, windows, shell, jq

We are trying to convert .geojson (openstreetmaps) to csv using 'jq' command in command line prompt. On running the following command:

`jq -r '(.features[0] | keys_unsorted), (.features[] | to_entries | map(.value[]))|@csv' temp.json`

It throws up this error
`jq: error (at gcc.geojson:1892525): Cannot iterate over string ("Feature").`

The gcc.geojson file contains 189252 lines. We need the columns: "coordinates", "properties" and properties's sub nests as columns in the .csv file. Sample content is as given below for your information

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[55.3139296,25.1810675]},"properties":{"highway":"motorway_junction"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[55.3048406,25.2769554]},"properties":{"highway":"traffic_signals"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[55.3064633,25.273499]},"properties":{"highway":"traffic_signals","traffic_signals":"signal"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[55.3160278,25.2672419]},"properties":{"highway":"traffic_signals","traffic_signals":"signal"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[55.3130749,25.2627212]},"properties":{"highway":"traffic_signals","traffic_signals":"signal"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[57.0755556,27.1506482]},"properties":{"int_name":"Minab","name":"میناب","addr:street":"Minab","name:ja":"ミーナーブ","name:ru":"Минаб","place":"town","population":"73170","population:date":"2016","source:population":"amar.org.ir","wikidata":"Q691052","wikipedia":"en:Minab"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[54.4249414,24.5382557]},"properties":{"addr:city":"Abu Dhabi","addr:neighbourhood":"St. Regis Saadiyat Island","addr:street":"St. Regis Saadiyat","contact:email":"spnstregis@spinneysauh.com","contact:facebook":"https://facebook.com/Spinneysbev","contact:instagram":"https://instagram.com/spinneysbev","contact:phone":"+971 2 676 6778","contact:twitter":"https://twitter.com/@spinneysbev","contact:website":"https://spinneysauh.com/","drive_through":"no","name":"Spinneys","opening_hours":"Fr 09:00-12:00,13:00-22:00;Mo-Th,Sa-Su 09:00-22:00","operator":"Spinneys","payment:cash":"yes","payment:credit_cards":"yes","shop":"alcohol"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[54.4250687,24.5383771]},"properties":{"addr:city":"Abu Dhabi","addr:neighbourhood":"St. Regis Saadiyat Island","addr:street":"St. Regis Saadiyat","name":"Spinney's Market","operator":"Spinney's","payment:cash":"yes","payment:coins":"yes","payment:credit_cards":"yes","shop":"supermarket"}},
```

The expected output is as given below:

`"54.4249414,24.5382557", "Abu Dhabi","St. Regis Saadiyat Island","St. Regis Saadiyat","contact:email":"spnstregis@spinneysauh.com",etc`

Any help on how to get the desired result would be much appreciated

Comment: The sample JSON does not have a key named "user" so it is not sufficiently representative of your actual data.  Also, it would be helpful to see the output you expect given your sample JSON, in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected the json command, still the same error.

Comment: What content is at *byte* 1892525 of the file?

Comment: Its the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not followed the [mcve] guidelines, and more specifically since
you have neither described your functional requirements nor shown the expected output corresponding plausibly to the shown input,
it is difficult to give more than a diagnosis for the problem you've encountered.

In brief, each "feature" is not a flat object, and so, since you want to use `@csv`, you're
going to have to specify how to represent each "feature" as a flat array.

This could be done in one of the following ways, but in each case, your headers are not going to match:

```
.features[] | [.. | scalars]
```

or

```
.features[] | [.geometry.coordinates[], .properties[]]
```

By the way, to debug your programs, you can use jq's `debug` filter.

Comment: In the revised Q, you've sometimes included keys ...